NEXT project using docker is not running in windows11 environment
It works in a LINUX environment, but not in a WINDOWS environment.
this is my dockerfile
# Stage 1: Base with pnpm installed
FROM node:lts-alpine as base
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Stage 2: Dependencies
FROM base as dependencies
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

# Stage 3: Build application
FROM dependencies as builder
COPY . .
RUN pnpm run build

# Stage 4: Production image
FROM base as production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node ./node_modules

USER node
EXPOSE 3000/tcp
CMD ["pnpm", "run", "start"]

# Optionally, add HEALTHCHECK as needed


and here is my docker-compose.yml file
services:
  admin-front:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: admin-front
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules 
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    command: pnpm run dev 

and this is my error
PS C:\dev\admin> docker compose up --build -d
...
------
 > [admin-front builder 2/2] RUN pnpm run build:
0.687 
0.687 > next14-app-router-mui-template@0.1.0 build /usr/src/app
0.687 > next build
0.687
0.722 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
0.722   throw err;
0.722   ^
0.722
0.722 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
0.722     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
0.722     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
0.722     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
0.722     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
0.722   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0.722   requireStack: []
0.722 }
0.722
0.722 Node.js v20.13.1
0.728  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

It works fine when run in the context of using MAC and WSL2.
However, it did not work in windows11 environment.
I can't figure out where the problem is at all

Your volumes: block is overwriting all of the code in your image with unpredictable content; what your application runs depends heavily on what's on the host system and what's in the anonymous Docker volume, and you lose the reproducibility that a Docker image brings.  Does deleting the volumes: block help?  (You should also be able to remove the container_name:, working_dir:, and command: overrides.)
